# Сортировка данных нажатием на кнопку ( PHP )

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, сортировка, запрос

Есть php код , который выводит из БД данные , нужно сделать кнопки на этой же странице, чтобы при нажатии происходила сортировка ( например нажал на первую кнопку , данные на странице отобразились по возрастанию поля id , нажал на вторую - по алфавиту )

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'название таблицы' ";
      $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
       echo '<table  >';
      $i = 0;
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
 { 
    if ($i == 0) {
          echo '<tr><td colspan="2" class="userinfo">User` s:'  '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '<tr><td class="info">';
    echo '<span class="score">' . $row['id'] . '</span><br />';
    echo '<strong>Name:</strong> ' . $row['name'] . '<br />';
      echo '<strong>Surname:</strong> ' . $row['player_surname'] . '<br />';
        echo '<strong>Birth Date:</strong> ' . $row['birth_date'] . '<br/>';
 $i++;
  }
  echo '</table>'; 

    mysqli_close($dbc);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно передавать параметр в URL с параметром, который будет регулировать ваш запрос, например: 
http://site.ru/?order=name&sort=desc

тогда в запросе меняете

```
SELECT * FROM 'название таблицы' ORDER BY name desc;
```

Конечно же не забываем проверять URL на sql-инъекции

Comment: Спасибо большое! Получилось